# Copy/Cut/Paste not available when editor is nested in a ScrollView in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, scrollview, editor

So my xaml looks like this

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Editor>

            </Editor>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The cut/copy/paste options are not available on long press in the editor but it works perfectly when the ScrollView is removed. Is there a way around this? Maybe with custom renderers as I don't seem to be the only one with the issue

Comment: Seems to be a bug you have caught. Does it work on iOS?

Comment: Haven't tried it on iOS but from all indications, it seems to be an Android problem as I'm not the only one facing this problem. There's even an open Github issue on it. I'm just trying to get a work around for the project I'm working on right now.

Comment: Can you share the link to the github issue. For the workaround, there’s a lot of things you could do, that would depend on the solution you’re trying to fix-you could try to use a custom control for the editor so that it uses the Android EditText and it contains the properties and functions you need

Comment: Here's the link https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8291

Comment: I added some comments in the issue on how you can fix the issue in Xamarin. For a workaround, Can you split the layout to 3, so that its scroll view, stacklayout containing the editor, and then another scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CustomRenderer to achieve it.

```
public class CustomEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer, Android.Views.View.IOnLongClickListener
{
    public CustomEditorRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null) { 

            Control.SetOnLongClickListener(this);

        }
    }
    public bool OnLongClick(Android.Views.View v)
    {
        Control.SetTextIsSelectable(true);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. But then my other mode of input (Speech to text) stopped working. I'm still trying to fix that.

Comment: You could create a separate renderer for this editor